# BigQuery Reddit Dataset: Collecting Comments from Subreddits?

Tags: google-bigquery, reddit

Very new to BigQuery and SQL in general! I found this amazing dataset of Reddit comments online (https://bigquery.cloud.google.com/table/fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_05) and would like to do some qualitative analysis on the comments.

**Question: How do I narrow my search to only retrieving comments and timestamps in the r/cancer subreddit and the r/diabetes subreddits? What is the exact query I should be using?**

I know this is probably really easy but I spent the past 4-5 hours on this and still cannot figure it out...

Answer (score 3):

```
SELECT subreddit, COUNT(*) c
FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_05] 
WHERE subreddit IN ('cancer', 'diabetes')
GROUP BY 1
LIMIT 1000

Query complete (1.6s elapsed, 595 MB processed)

Row subreddit   c    
1   diabetes    6508     
2   cancer      1923
```

For the raw comments and timestamps:

```
SELECT subreddit, created_utc, body
FROM [fh-bigquery:reddit_comments.2015_05] 
WHERE subreddit IN ('cancer', 'diabetes')
LIMIT 10
```

Comment: It works, Felipe! Thank you, so, so much for your help in this! I really appreciate it!